# Make view to overlap AppBarLayout

Tags: android, android-layout

I'm trying to show fullscreen overlay view and first step is to setup xml with hidden overlay, then show it when appropriate. Here is my layout:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/activity_main"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
        android:id="@+id/appBar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">
        <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
            android:id="@+id/toolbar"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
            android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"/>
    </android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@+id/appBar"
        android:textColor="#FFFFFF"
        android:text="Hello World!" />

    <View
        android:id="@+id/overlay"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:clickable="true"
        android:background="#80FF0000"/>
</RelativeLayout>
```

Here is a result:

[image]

And I need result like that:

[image]

So, I'm successfully overlap all the screen except AppBarLayout. How to make my view to be placed over and not behind AppBarLayout?

Comment: Hey @WhiteNinja, is my answer solved your problem?

Comment: @Karoly, nope.. My question is why View with id "overlay" is not overlapping AppBarLayout and how to fix it.

Answer (score 1):

You should use this code in your activity:

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    // If the Android version is lower than Jellybean, use this call to hide
    // the status bar.
    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT < 16) {
        getWindow().setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN,
                WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN);
    }
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
}
...
```

}

You can follow this official google tutorial:
https://developer.android.com/training/system-ui/status.html

Comment: This answer is not for my question... And my minSdk is 19